# Adding files to build package artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm following a learning course on plural-sight and he shows an artifact with cfg folder and json file within that folder(outside of the packge.zip file) but I cant figure out how he managed to configure his build process to get that file there.

[image]

How do I achieve this and where should i go to learn more about package files how they are made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the "drop" folder gets included in the default "Publish Build Artifacts" Task, just add your files in the drop folder (or subfolders there).

The variable with the path is called: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`

This images shows a newly created "Publish Build Artifacts" task:
[image]

Something similar is probably creating your artifact, check for it in your build definition.